# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, ecommerce website

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a simple eCommerce page and I have a problem

I tried assigning the addItemToCart function to an "a" tag in html, but i get the syntax error

Can someone help me solve this, I'm a begginer and I'm trying to make a shopping cart using javascript, but it seems like I got something wrong and I don't know what

```
var cart = [];

var Item = function(nume, pret, nrbuc) {
    this.nume = nume
    this.pret = pret
    this.nrbuc = nrbuc
};

function addItemToCart(nume, pret, nrbuc) {
    for (var i in cart) {
        if (cart[i].nume === nume) {
            cart[i].nrbuc += nrbuc;
            return;
        }
    }
    var item = new Item(nume, pret, nrbuc);
    cart.push(item);
}

function removeItemFromCart(nume) {
    for (var i in cart) {
        if (cart[i].nume === nume) {
            cart[i].nrbuc--;
            if (cart[i].nrbuc === 0) {
                cart.splice(i, 1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

function removeItemFromCartAll(nume) {
    for (var i in cart) {
        if (cart[i].nume === nume) {
            cart.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function clearCart() {
    cart = [];
}
```

Comment: The code presented here works fine - there is no error. It must come from elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Should i post the whole html page here?

Comment: `For .. in` loop is for objects, try with `for..of` loop, assuming i is index

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m2R9rrQ3, this is the complete code, i have problems with the href="javascript:addItemToCart("tricou", 59.00, 1)"

Comment: `href="javascript:addItemToCart("tricou", 59.00, 1)"` you use double quotes `"` for both the `href` and the string `"tricou"`. This causes the problem, as the opening quote for the string actually closes the href  - you effectively have `href="javascript:addItemToCart("`. Switch to using single quotes for one of these - either the href or the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. <3